# i want to execute a saved query in the database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to execute a query that i saved in my database like this:

```
ID | NAME          | QUERY
 1 | show_names    | "SELECT names.first, names.last FROM names;"
 2 | show_5_cities | "SELECT cities.city FROM city WHERE id = 4;"
```

Is this possible ?
I am kinda noob in php so plz explain if it is possible.

Comment: *Why* do you have an idea of storing queries in database?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Storing queries in a database is a quick way of creating a user-customizable reporting system if they have their own queries that they want to run.

Comment: It seems you are under some sort of strong delusion.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936273/execute-a-saved-query-then-make-a-csv-out-of-it-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have your queries saved in the database in a table and you want to execute those.

Break the problem down: you have two tasks to do:

1. Query the database for the query you want to run.
2. Execute that query.

It's a bit meta, but meh :)

**WARNING: the `mysql_` functions in PHP are deprecated and can be dangerous in the wrong hands.**

```
<?php

if (!$link = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')) {
    die('Could not connect to mysql');
}

if (!mysql_select_db('mysql_dbname', $link)) {
    die('Could not select database');
}

$name   = "show_5_cities"; // or get the name from somewhere, e.g. $_GET.
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name); // sanitize, this is important!
$sql    = "SELECT `query` FROM `queries` WHERE `name` = '$name'"; // I should be using parameters here...
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

if (!$result) {
    die("DB Error, could not query the database\n" . mysql_error(););
}

$query2 = mysql_fetch_array($result);
// Improving the code here is an exercise for the reader.
$result = mysql_query($query2[0]);

?>
```

Comment: +1 just make sure you can trust the queries that are going in here, sanitize prior to insert.

Answer (score 0):

if you did create a stored procedure/function you can simply use:

```
mysql_query("Call procedure_name(@params)")
```

Thats will work. reference here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php

Answer (score 0):

Querying the table to get the query, then executing that query and looping through the results and outputting the fields

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$RequiredQuery = intval($_REQUEST['RequiredQuery']);
$sql    = "SELECT `QUERY` FROM QueryTable WHERE ID = $RequiredQuery";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $sql    = "SELECT `QUERY` FROM QueryTable WHERE ID = $RequiredQuery";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $row['QUERY']);

    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        foreach($row2 AS $aField=>$aValue)
        {
            echo "$aField \t $aValue \r\n";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

just open the Table and get the individual query in a variable like

```
$data = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM <the Table that contains your Queries>');

while(($row = mysql_fetch_row($data)) != NULL)
{
    $query = $row['Query'];
    mysql_query($query);   // The Query from the Table will be Executed Individually in a loop

}
```

if you want to execute a single query from the table, you have to select the query using `WHERE` Clause.